# Laravel BelongsToMany Error - Base table or view not found

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I hope this thread find everyone healthy.

What is wrong with the following code? I am getting an error on my many to many relationship. For the past 4 hours i am stuck with this problem. I would be very thankful if you find the bug or source of problem.

Here is my code and tables:

```
Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category');
        $table->string('thumbnail');
        $table->string('images');
        $table->string('logo');
        $table->string('main_photo');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    //categories table
    Schema::create('product_categories', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('category');
    });

    //relationship table
    Schema::create('product_productcategory', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('product_id'); // the id of the bear
        $table->integer('productcategories_id'); // the id of the picnic that this bear is at
    });
```

products model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
protected $table = 'products';

public function product_category() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\product_category', 'App\product_productcategory', 'product_id', 'productcategories_id');
}

}
```

And pivot model

```
class product_category extends Model
{
protected $table = 'product_categories';

public function product() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'App\product_productcategory', 'productcategories_id', 'product_id');
}   

}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

Updates: The problem is solved thanks to @mimo.
But now i want to translate the categories in different languages so i created a table like this:

```
Schema::create('category_translations', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');

        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('locale_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('locale_id')->references('id')->on('locales')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unique(['category_id', 'locale_id']);

    });
```

And my product categories with new relationship to the translations

```
class product_category extends Model
{
protected $table = 'product_categories';

public function product() {
    //return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'App\product_productcategory', 'productcategories_id', 'product_id');
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_productcategory');
}

public function translation($lang) {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category_Translation')->where('locale_id', '=', $lang);
}

}
```

And in category translation:

```
class Category_Translation extends Model
{
protected $table = 'category_translations';

public function product_category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\product_category');
}
}
```

And finally my Product:

```
class Product extends Model
{
protected $table = 'products';

public function translation($lang) {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product_Translation')->where('locale_id', '=', $lang);
}

public function product_category() {
    //return $this->belongsToMany('App\product_category', 'App\product_productcategory', 'product_id', 'productcategories_id');
    //return $this->belongsToMany('App\product_category', 'product_productcategory');
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\product_category', 'product_productcategory')->translation(1);
}

}
```

Now when i run:

```
$product = App\Product::find(1)->first();
echo $product->product_category;
```

I get error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::translation()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your migration file is wrong:

```
//relationship table
Schema::create('product_productcategory', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index(); // the id of the bear
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
    $table->integer('productcategories_id')->unsigned()->index(); // the id of the picnic that this bear is at
    $table->foreign('productcategories_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories');
});
```

This code will made the relationship on the database level.

When you have 12 min free time you can check out this tutorial about many to many relationships in laravel:
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/21

Update:

you need to update your relationships too:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function product_category() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\product_category', 'product_productcategory');
    }

}
```

and:

```
class product_category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product_categories';

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_productcategory');
    }   

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, i changed the code with yours and still the same error...

My route.php code:
    $product = App\Product::find(1)->product_category()->first();
    echo $product;

And error msg:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project.app\product_productcategory' doesn't exist

Comment: My fault, you have to update your models too. Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks you very much!!!. It solved the problem...i am still confused what was the problem because i had manually defined the column names?

And one more question please. forgive my ignorance, i am not experienced in db relationships. How to combine this 2 objects, the product and product_categories. because right now i have to do 2 seperate requests like: App\Product::find(1)->first(); to get the product itself and another request App\Product::find(1)->product_category()->first(); to get the product category.

Comment: You can use `App\Product->width('product_category')->find(1);`. It will return a product with a loaded category.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. You have saved my day today. But there is now 1 last problem...
I have now created a translation table but i don't know how to relate them in laravel. Please check my updated question, i have posted the codes what i have done. Thank you